# How can i set the specific minimum version for Project References in a Nuget Package?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, nuget-package

I have two solutions:

***Solution A***

- Project "A.Application" (0.0.1-alpha3)
- Project "A.Domain" (0.0.1-alpha2)
- Project "A.Infrastructure"  (0.0.1-alpha2)

*A.Application references A.Domain and A.Infrastructure as a ProjectReference.*

***Solution B***

- Project "B.WebUI"

*B.WebUI consumes each Project from A as separate Nugetpackage.*

---

**What i do:**

Now i make a change in one Library. I publish the package to our local Nuget-Source **in the Package Manager Console** and increase the Prerelease-Number:

```
dotnet pack .\A.Application --version-suffix "-alpha.4" --output "mypath"
```

**Problem:**

When i want to update the Project "A.Application" in B.WebUI over the Nuget-Package-Explorer to the newest version i get following errors:

```
Unable to find package A.Domain with version (>= 0.0.1-alpha.4)
Unable to find package A.Infrastructure with version (>= 0.0.1-alpha.4)
```

*alpha4* does not exist because this packages are still in *alpha2*. I don't want to pack all unchanged libraries again and again to match the same number.

**Question:**

**How can i define that A.Applicaton should still be happy with older versions?** Do i have to specify a nuspec file or ist there another possibility inside the **PMC** or the **Project-File**?

**Edit:**

The contents of the nupkg. The depencies are also incremented to alpha6 because this dlls are added as projectreferences:
[image]

Comment: Why is B.WebUI using the same version for all three NuGet Packages?

Comment: To allow for older and newer versions use a [floating version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#floating-versions) in the package reference, e.g. `<PackageReference Include="A.Application" Version="0.*" />`.

Comment: @JonathanDodds B.WebUI is not using alle the same versions. 

The problem is A.Application publish a nugetfile which demands the package  "A.Domain in version 0.0.1-alpha4" although there is only existing a version 0.0.1-alpha2 in the nuget source.

That is because i added A.Domain as Projectreference and not as Nugetpackage (because i am already in the same solution).

Comment: Does the A.Application package include the A.Domain contents? It sounds like the A.Application package either already has the A.Domain contents and shouldn't have a NuGet dependency or the A.Application package has a NuGet dependency and it incorrectly using its own version for the A.Domain dependency.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I added a screenshot to the original post of the created package. The referenced A.Domain contents are not in the package. But there are nuget-depencies on A.Domain which Visual Studio of course wants me to generate them too (it does not know that a A.Domain in Version 0.0.1-alpha.4 already exists because i didnt referenced it as nuget to A.Aplication).

When i add PrivateAssets="All" to the ProjectReferences the depencies on the bottom left are gone and they are also not added to the package on the right.

Comment: How are you specifying the NuGet dependencies while using `ProjectRerefence`'s?

Comment: That is what i dont understand exactly. I don't specify any NuGet depencies. I just add the  Inside-Same-Solution-Projects as normal ProjectReferences.